# using didUpdateWidget to replace a stream causes "bad state: Stream has already been listened to"

Tags: flutter, stream-builder

I have a StreamBuilder that I want to be able to pause and unpause and, since StreamBuilder [doesn't expose it's underlying StreamSubscription](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28117), I have to create a proxy stream to forward the source stream's elements while exposing a StreamSubscription that I can pause and unpause. This forces me to convert my stateless widget into a stateful widget so I have access to dispose and can close it's StreamController.

I'm following the [didUpdateWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html) documentation's instructions:

> In initState, subscribe to the object.
> In didUpdateWidget unsubscribe from the old object and subscribe to the new one if the updated widget configuration requires replacing the object.
> In dispose, unsubscribe from the object.

I need to replace the Stream whenever the user types in a new search query. My stateful widget is re-constructed within a ChangeNotifier whenever a new stream is received.

Here's the relevant part of my stateful widget:

```
  final Stream<List<Entry>> _entryStream;
  StreamController<List<Entry>> _entryStreamController;
  StreamSubscription<List<Entry>> _entryStreamSubscription;

  _EntryListState(this._entryStream);

  void initStream() {
    _entryStreamController?.close();
    _entryStreamController = StreamController();

    _entryStreamSubscription = _entryStream.listen((event) {
      _entryStreamController.add(event);
    }
    )..onDone(() => _entryStreamController.close());
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    initStream();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _entryStreamController?.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(EntryList oldEntryList) {
    // Initialize the stream only if it has changed
    if (oldEntryList._entryStream != _entryStream) initStream();

    super.didUpdateWidget(oldEntryList);
  }
```

This is the line throwing the BadState error:

```
    _entryStreamSubscription = _entryStream.listen((event) {
      _entryStreamController.add(event);
    }
```

And here is where my widget is being constructed:

```
              child: Consumer<SearchStringModel>(
                builder: (context, searchStringModel, child) {
                  print('rebuilding with: ${searchStringModel.searchString}');
                  var entryStream = _getEntries(searchStringModel.searchString);
                  return EntryList(entryStream);
                }
              ),
```

I don't think I understand didUpdateWidget in particular and suspect that's where the two issues (bad state, and not updating) are coming from? I'm also re-constructed the stateful widget instead of just modifying its state which is a little confusing, but the widget is intended to act as a stateless widget for all intents and purposes so it'd be a pain to update it to update state instead of reconstructing. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had not read the "didUpdateWidget" documentation closely enough. This is the key paragraph:

```
  /// If the parent widget rebuilds and request that this location in the tree
  /// update to display a new widget with the same [runtimeType] and
  /// [Widget.key], the framework will update the [widget] property of this
  /// [State] object to refer to the new widget and then call this method
  /// with the previous widget as an argument.
```

In my consumer, I'm rebuilding with a new `EntryList`. As the above paragraph describes, the framework will then call `didUpdateWidget` on the **same** state object (as opposed to a new one). In order to check whether or not the configuration has changed and, if it has, to access the new configuration, I need to access the `widget` property of my state object. With this in mind, here is my new implementation of `didUpdateWidget`:

```
  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(EntryList oldEntryList) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldEntryList);
    // Initialize the stream only if it has changed
    if (widget._entryStream != _entryStream) {
      _entryStream = widget._entryStream;
      initStream();
    }
  }
```

Note that I am now checking `widet._entryStream` and then setting the state's `_entryStream` to it if it's changed.

Hopefully someone else running into a similar problem will be helped by this!